# Создать два стека C++

Tags: c++, стек

Есть код для создания стека, нужно создать еще один.

```
struct Steck
{
    int number;
    Steck *last;
};
Steck *ptrLast = NULL;
Steck *top = NULL;
void createFirstSteck()
{
    int temp;
    cout << "Введите число: "; cin >> temp;
    Steck *ptr = new Steck;
    ptr->number = temp;
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        ptr->last = NULL;
        top = ptr;
        ptrLast = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        top = ptr;
        ptr->last = ptrLast;
        ptrLast = ptr;
    }
    cout << "Что дальше?" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
}
```

Comment: ctrl + c ctrl + v?

Comment: Просто создать 2 объект? `Steck *ptr2 = new Steck;`

Answer (score 2):

Что дальше? Дальше нужно убрать все лишнее и вызывать функцию.

```
struct Steck
{
    int number = 0;   // значение по умолчанию
    Steck* last = NULL; // по умолчанию нулевой
};


Steck* top = NULL;
void createFirstSteck()
{   
    if (!top) 
        top =  new Steck;       
    else
    {   
        Steck* ptr = new Steck;
        ptr->last = top;
        top = ptr;
    }
    cout << "Введите число: ";
    cin >> top->number;     
}
```

Сколько раз вызовете функцию, столько обьектов будут в списке, и каждый раз `top`будет указывать на вершину стека(адрес последнего). Кстати  стек пишется **не** `Steck` **а**  `Stack`. Для того, чтобы создать  стек, напишем  функцию, вызывающую createFirstSteck() и заодно пусть займется и выводом на консоль:

```
//создать  стек
void createNextStack(const size_t size)
{
    top = NULL;
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= size; ++i)
        createFirstSteck(); 
    for (Steck* ptr = top; ptr; ptr = ptr->last)
        cout << ptr->number << ' ';
}
```

Например, создадим список из трех обьектов, а потом создадим другой список из пяти обьектов:

```
int main()
{   
    createNextStack(3);
    createNextStack(5);
    //не забывать об освобождении памяти
    return 0;
}
```

особенность стека в том, что последный вытаскивается первым, поэтому держать два указателья никчему. В общем случаи структуру(класс) нужно обеспечивать подходящими функциональностьми, но это другая тема...